# How to give multi-device support in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am newbie to Xamarin development.

In android we have different values folder for multi-device support.

But In Xamarin forms how we give multi-device support for Android & iOS?

Anyone don't know about ***what is multi-device support*** pls check the sample document by Android
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I want similar like this for Xamarin forms.

**Note:** I am asking about ***Xamarin forms*** not in native code.

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Negative voters need to mention the reason also.

Comment: What's you mean "different values folder for multi-device support"? Different layout file?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT are you don't aware of multi-device support in Android? If anybody don't know pls type the "Multi-device support in Android" you will get answer. https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I understand the multi-device support, in Xamarin.Forms project, **Provide different layouts for different screen sizes** did not work anymore, since Xamarin.Forms has its own layout in PCL,  **Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities** still did work in Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT pls read question once again. I am asking about Xamarin forms. I already mentioned in **Note: I am asking about Xamarin forms not in native code.** No documentation about multi-device support in Xamarin forms. No questions in SO. no one answer for Xamarin questions. Hate Xamarin now

Comment: Sorry for any inconvenience, and please wait a moment, I will give you some information about this.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT thanks for the reply

Comment: Is this can help you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to give multi-device support in Xamarin Forms

#### Xamarin.Forms XAML Support :

`Xamarin.Forms` use the platform-specific mechanisms to calculate the absolute pixel dimensions. As [Digitalsa1nt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45161693/how-to-develop-xamarin-forms-app-for-phone-and-tablet) said, `Xamarin.Forms` uses `xaml` as it's base markup language for renderng displays, and converts this into the native counterparts at runtime. Usually, you don't have to care about the resolution, it will adjust the views based on your layout and constraints.

---

#### Some useful link about Xamarin.Forms multi-device support :

- [Bringing Xamarin.Forms Apps to Tablets](https://blog.xamarin.com/bringing-xamarin-forms-apps-to-tablets/)

  - Provides a few nice helper methods to extend the app for a better tablet experience
- [Device Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/device/)

  - The Device class contains a number of properties and methods to help developers customize layout and functionality on a per-platform basis.
- [Layout for Tablet and Desktop apps](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/tablet/)

  - Discuss about the supported device types, and how to optimize layouts for tablets versus phones.
- [Cross-platform Image optimisation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/)

  - Images can be shared across platforms with Xamarin.Forms, they can be loaded specifically for each platform, or they can be downloaded for display.
- [Master Detail Pages](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage/)

  - Ideal for focusing on just large screen devices

---

## Update :

You could read this official document: [Dealing with sizes](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05/) and the related [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/tree/master/Chapter05). It demonstrates many solutions to solve your problem :

- [Platform-specific font size](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/tree/master/Chapter05/FontSizes)
- [Metrical sizes](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05/#Metrical_sizes)
- [Estimated font sizes](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05/#Estimated_font_sizes)
- [Fitting text to available size](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05/#Fitting_text_to_available_size)
- [Empirically fitting text](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05/#Empirically_fitting_text)
- [A fit-to-size clock](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05/#A_fit-to-size_clock)
- [Accessibility issues](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05/#Accessibility_issues)

For example : the [Platform-specific font size at no cost](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-VisualStudio-Dev/Xamonday-Show-Platform-specific-font-size-at-no-cost)

In some cases we need to assign a different font size to controls based on the specific operating system's styles, avoiding hard-coded values. Through the Device class, `Xamarin.Forms` makes this possible at no cost.

In your `Page` `OnAppearing()` method :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    this.LargeLabel.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label));
    this.SmallLabel.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label));
    this.MediumLabel.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label));
}
```

Effect :

[image]

Comment: all the links are helpful. But I want textsize changes for various devices. for ex: if we give the textsize= 12 it feel good in mobiles. But in 7 inch or 9 inch tablets it looks very small. How you handle this case? I need answer for this question only

Comment: @RanjithKumar, you can use [Device.Idiom](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Device.Idiom/) to detect if the current device is a phone or tablet, then you could set a bigger textsize for tablets.

Comment: yes Device.Idiom is good choice. But how you handle 7inch & 10inch tablets we apply the same textsize for both 7inch & 10inch ahh? Because if we apply the big textsize for tablets based on Device.Idiom it works good for high resolution tablets. But low resolution tablets it looks very big. This reason only In Android we use different values folder & mention the text size values on each folder.If we use Idiom how we handle this cases?

Comment: @RanjithKumar, as a workaround, you could detect your device screen size and then according to the screen size to set a suitable textsize.

Comment: Your answer not exact solution for this question. For iOS  your solution surely it will works. But Android your solution not fix for all devices like low density tablets, high density phones. Looking for 100% working answer. I already research & found the solution for android also. I will post my answer later

Comment: @RanjithKumar, I have updated my answer, hope this can help you. :)

Comment: Thanks for updated answer. I accept this answer now. I also have android device specific font size related code. I will post this answer later.