# Xamarin Forms - Get Named Size Does Not Work well with Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Device.GetNamedSize works as expected with iOS but Android sizes are not scaling appropriately at all. Has anyone else experienced this? I have resorted to implementing these controls natively which drives me insane.

Thanks for your time everyone.

Comment: Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056100/how-to-give-multi-device-support-in-xamarin-forms/48078850#48078850

Answer (score 0):

The book "[Creating Mobile Apps with Xamarin.Forms Book First Edition](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/)" in chapter 5 has a section ("Accessibility issues") about scaling on iOS and Android when using Settings. See also [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/tree/master/Chapter05/AccessibilityTest). The next section of the book "Empirically fitting text" [within a rectangle], suggests a possible solution; see [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/tree/master/Chapter05/EmpiricalFontSize).